# Import PDF file into XeLaTeX gives "pdf_link_obj(): passed invalid object" error

Tags: pdf, latex, pdftk, xelatex

I'm trying to import a PDF into a XeLaTeX using `\includepdf{xyz.pdf}`. The file `xyz.pdf` is a scan created by a Xerox 5755 machine, and PDF version 1.3.

The error I get is:

```
   ** WARNING ** No valid name object found.
   ** WARNING ** Could not find a value in dictionary object.
   ** WARNING ** Didn't find "endobj".
   ** ERROR ** pdf_link_obj(): passed invalid object.
```

I've tried normalizing the PDF by running `pdftk xyz.pdf output xyz2.pdf`, and that *does* resolve the issue — but only for some PDF files, with no obvious relationship between those files `pdftk` fixes and those it does not. There are always some files normalized with `pdftk` that continue to exhibit the exact same error as the unnormalized file.

I've tried searching for a solution to this issue and come up with this thread: [XeLaTeX problems with includegraphics](http://macosx-tex.576846.n2.nabble.com/XeLaTeX-problems-with-includegraphics-td834042.html), which suggests that the problem can be solved by using the `-output-driver=xdv2pdf`, or alternatively by using `pdf(la)tex`. Alas, I can't use PdfLaTeX because I need XeLaTeX's unicode support. As well, I'm using Linux so I can't use the Mac-specific `xdv2pdf`.

I'd be very much obliged for any thoughts and input on why these PDF's are failing to be loaded by XeLaTeX, and — better still — how one might 'fix' these PDFs.

Kind regards,

Brian

Comment: Got the same issue. I tried  xelatex -no-pdf latexdoc.tex then  xdvipdfmx -V 5 latexdoc.xdv to use a newer version of PDF, but it didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luatex (successor to Pdftex) also supports Unicode natively.  What happens when you try compiling using `lualatex`?

Comment: Almost 12 years later this answer still solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue using XeLaTeX on Debian. PDFs exported from LibreOffice were imported properly, while including scans as PDFs which were created by my printer failed.

I could fix this issue by "re-compilig" the PDF with Ghostscript. 
On Linux this would be done with:

```
gs -o repaired.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress corrupted.pdf
```

(source: https://superuser.com/a/282056, there's also the Ghostscript command for Windows)

Importing the "repaired" PDF with XeLaTeX worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was using \includegraphics{} and struck a similar problem with a pdf (created by printing a file from Excel using Win2pdf). I opened the pdf with Adobe Reader and saved a copy. The copy was then successfully incorporated using \includgraphics{} and the xelatex compiler.